# Creating a stylesheet and applying it on a html macro in confluence

Tags: css, confluence

I was able to add inline styles to the HTML Macros, but i felt the HTML Macro is clumsy because of too many styles. So i would like to seperate CSS into seperate file and link that stylesheet to the HTML Macro. Can someone suggest how can i achieve this in Confluence.

Note: I have Admin Rights and i want apply styles to that specific Page.